# How to convert .doc to ODF with a command line?

Tags: text-processing, command, conversion, libreoffice, openoffice

I'd like to convert many Microsoft Word documents to ODF (the OO.org formata with a command line (because there are many of them).

(I need them for reading afterwards on a device where reading OO.org format is possible, but not the .doc format -- actually, an Android with only free software, such as [OpenDocument Reader](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=opendocument&fdid=at.tomtasche.reader), primarily from F-Droid packages repository.)

What can I use as the commmand for such a conversion?

Comment: Did you mean convert to ODF format?

Comment: @masegaloeh Yes, ODF. Thanks for helping to remember the name.

Comment: `unoconv` would be the command.

Answer (score 4):

Using **unoconv** would your best bet, it doesn't even need **OpenOffice**/**LibreOffice** installed.

From its [home page](https://github.com/dagwieers/unoconv):

> **unoconv** converts between any document format that **OpenOffice** understands. It uses **OpenOffice's** UNO bindings for non-interactive conversion of documents.

Comment: Just to clear up some misconceptions, unoconv does need OpenOffice/LibreOffice installed, even when using a remote instance for doing the actual conversion. AFAIK there is no other/independent UNO implementation than the one that ships with OpenOffice/LibreOffice :-/